# How do you add Master nodes in an ACS-Engine templated cluster?

Tags: docker-swarm, azure-container-service

I have a running cluster that was created by a ACS-Engine template deployment following this guide: https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine/blob/master/docs/swarmmode.md

I want to add extra Master nodes to my running cluster... 
Say I have 3 Master nodes and I want to scale that to 5. Or similarly, say one of my 3 master VMs crashes, can't be recovered and it needs to be replaced.

What is the right way to add a new Master node VM to my cluster?

Comment: Hi Jack from the ACS team. So our cloud init scripts etc. currently assumes masters are static. I know for supporting upgrade we are adding the ability to bring up a new node and move the etcd disks to a new master vm. That however doesn't allow adding more masters. So if you figure it out. please post here as it would be awesome info. But it currently isn't a supported scenario so you'd need to figure out how on your own.

Comment: @JackQuincy I wasn't able to find a away to add master nodes. I am using the https://github.com/Azure/azurefile-dockervolumedriver for my persistent storage so I had to destroy the whole cluster and recreate with an updated "masterProfile": { "count": xx } value in the template. Not ideal given that this approach involves down-time.